# Ошибка конфигурации SSL ключа (0906D064)

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

Пытаюсь добавить SSL на свой сайт, но появляется ошибка при проверке  конфигурации
 **(SSL: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)**

По этому мануалу проверил хэш https://ma.ttias.be/nginx-ssl-certificate-errors-pem_read_bio_x509_aux-pem_read_bio_x509-ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file/ увидел что хэш ключа отличается от сертификата, но как бы я не пытался изменить хэш ключа, он остаётся одним и тем же.

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/domain.ru/certificate.key  2> /dev/null | openssl md5
(stdin)= d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Да же если удалить сам ключ, хэш почему то остаётся тот же самый.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что да же если этот ключ удалить с сервера (сам файл) хэш почему то всё равно такой же. Или если оставить этот файл пустым, хэш такой же. Как будто он этот файл и вовсе не видит.

Comment: Получается вот такой ответ: `139741095212688:error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:818:`

Comment: А могли неверный ключ прислать? У меня в файле кроме содержания самого ключа и заголовков -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- больше ничего нет. Сам сертификат я создавал таким же образом (только ключей там больше), но с ним нет проблем.

Comment: Спасибо, обратился в тех поддержку, мне отправили повторно письмо видимо оно оказалось битым до этого, т.к. ключ который мне отправили изначально отличался от того который переотправили. И теперь всё заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SSL: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib

ошибка здесь следующая:

> bad base64 decode error

говорит она о том, что либо файл с сертификатом, либо файл с ключом содержат некорректную информацию, которую не удаётся декодировать с помощью [схемы base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

о том, какой именно из файлов некорректен, подсказывает название функции, в которой произошла ошибка:

> SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file

функция [SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file) предназначена для чтения ключа из указанного файла.

---

убедиться в некорректности можно, например, запросив «отпечаток» (fingerprint, modulus) ключа:

```
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /путь/к/файлу/с/ключом
```

если файл корректный, будет выдано что-то вроде этого (длинная строка шестнадцатиричных цифр сокращена):

```
Modulus=9F3A2FB31...5F0AFDA221
```

если же файл «битый», будет получена какая-нибудь ошибка:

```
unable to load Private Key
3074533640:error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:818:
```

или:

```
unable to load Private Key
3074353416:error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line:pem_lib.c:804:
```

или даже просто:

```
unable to load Private Key
```

в зависимости от того, *как именно* повреждено содержимое файла.